# AFAIK, the code below shouldn't compile, but it does in clang and GCC. What am I missing here?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

The code below shows a union-like class with a non-trivial default constructor (member `y` is initialized with a *brace-or-equal-initializer*), so if a default constructor for such a class is defaulted, it should be deleted according to §12.1/5 first bullet point. That is, the declaration `T t;` should not compile, as there is no default constructor for the `union T`. But the [code compiles and executes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a72e7785386e32c8) in clang and GCC.

```
#include <iostream>
union T
{
    int y{1};
    float x;
    char c;
    T() = default;
};

int main()
{
    T t;
    std::cout << t.y << '\n';
}
```

**EDIT**

My question above was wrong right from the start, as the union T is **not** a *union-like class*. I just came to know about §9.5/8 in C++11 which says:

> A *union-like class* is a union or a class that has an anonymous union
>   as a direct member. A union-like class X has a set of *variant members*.
>   If X is a union its variant members are the non-static data members;
>   otherwise, its variant members are the non-static data members of all
>   anonymous unions that are members of X.

Now, consider the snippet below. It doesn't compile because the default constructor for the union is deleted. But I still, don't know which bullet point in §12.1/5 is reponsible for this result. Note that again, the union is not a *union-like class* and so, the first bullet point in §12.1/5 doesn't apply. But that's what the error message says in both clang and GCC. See [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/261d1d2e5414a8c9).

```
#include <iostream>

union T{
    int y;
    struct A{ int i; A():i{1} {} } a;
};

int main()
{
    T t;
    std::cout << t.a.i << '\n';
}
```

Comment: "A default constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is od-rused" Because your constructor appears to be odr-used, shouldn't it be valid code?

Comment: It also compiles for VS 2015 Preview without issues.

Comment: What is the purpose of a union that you can't instantiate in any way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bullet is

> `X` is a union-like class that has a variant member with a non-trivial
>   default constructor

which is parsed as

> `X` is a union-like class that has (a variant member with a non-trivial
>   default constructor)

i.e., "with a non-trivial default constructor" applies to the type of the variant member, not `X`.

Comment: Even so, isn't the default constructor for `y` non-trivial? Or maybe the concept of non-triviality doesn't apply to a built-in type?

Comment: @Ayrosa `y` is an `int`, which like all primitive types has no constructors. Let alone non-trivial constructors. The *brace-or-equal-initializer* `{1}` in the definition `int y{1};` is not a constructor for `y`, it's used to initialize `y` in the *union's* constructors when no other initializer is provided. In other words, the presence of that `{1}` means that your `T() = default;` has the same effect as `T() : y{1} {}`.

Comment: @T.C. Would you mind to comment on my **Edit** above?

Comment: @Ayrosa It's parsed as "A union-like class is (a union) or (a class that has an anonymous union as a direct member)". A union is a union-like class.

Comment: @T.C. I can't believe I didn't see this from the beginning. Thanks anyway (+1).